# Unable to boot Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 8 ..

Tags: dual-boot

I have dell N5010 laptop with windows 8. Yesterday I installed ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop but I m unable boot with ubuntu. whenever I restart my system it directly goes to windows. there is no option like secure boot or legacy boot in my bios

Thanks

Comment: You can use Easybcd(http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) in Windows to add an entry in Windows bootloader for ubuntu.I hope a windows solution is also sounds nice :)

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Ubuntu? When you boot into Ubuntu, there are 3 options. One is showing dual boot, second one clears Windows and installs Ubuntu and third one is something like advanced options.

If you used 3rd one, try re-installing with 1st option. Ubuntu will setup everything for you and after POST screen before OS loads, Ubuntu will welcome you with start-up options (Load Ubuntu, Load Windows etc.).

I had the same issue. I've chosen 3rd option and installed Ubuntu on the other partition and after installation complete my pc loaded Windows directly without asking me which OS I prefer. After that I re-installed Ubuntu with 1st option which was showing me dual OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use your LiveCD/DVD or LiveUSB to login to a live session of Ubuntu(when the prompt to install or try Ubuntu comes, use try Ubuntu). You will then need to install boot-repair. To do that, after the desktop has loaded press Ctrl+Alt+T, this will launch Terminal. Now in the terminal type these one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

This will install boot-repair, after the installation is finished, type

```
sudo boot-repair
```

in the terminal, which will open boot-repair. Wait for boot-repair to finish its detections and select "Recommended Repair" when the prompt comes. Wait for it to finish, reboot your computer.
Hopefully that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the quick boot feature in Windows 8, otherwise the system will boot directly into windows completely ignoring the grub configuration. You can find it in the energy section in Windows 8 control panel.